# UITest searchBar detection fails in Xcode 11.1 when just assigning title to navigationItem

Tags: xcode11, xcuitest

When I'm assigning a title to the navigationItem, it fails to detect a searchBar

UITest fails in Xcode 11.1 when assigning title to navigationItem. If I do no assign a title to the navigation item, it just works.

This used to work in previous versions of Xcode 10.x

Here is a sample code. Do you know why this is happening?

https://github.com/nico-miyasato/uiSearchBarTesting/

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, your committed code does not seem to contain the function you are asking about. How about a link to the failing code in context?

Comment: Hey now the code is pushed. Thanks!